# Spring security redirect to 404 page issue

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

I try to apply spring security on my webapp to request the user to create or login to an account before using the app. However, the page can not display the login or register page but 404 page. I have been trying to look around but still could not find the root of the problem. Can someone help to detect the problem please.

This is my web.xml

```
<listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener> 

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            classpath:spring-servlet.xml,
            classpath:spring-security.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>defaultHtmlEscape</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>


    <!-- Ensure one session per request
    -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>hibernateFilter</filter-name>
            <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-class>
            <init-param>
             <param-name>sessionFactoryBeanName</param-name>
             <param-value>sessionFactory</param-value>         
        </init-param>      
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>hibernateFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping> 

    <!-- 
    <filter>
        <filter-name>encoding-filter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>
            org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter
        </filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>encoding-filter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    -->

    <!-- 
        Enables Spring Security
    -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <!-- 
        Direct Servlet Dispatcher beans
    -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class> org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value></param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>


    <!-- Restrict dispatcher views -->
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>


    <!-- Handle NotFound Error Page -->
    <error-page>
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>/WEB-INF/views/errors/404.jsp</location>
    </error-page>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
```

And this is my spring-security.xml:

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">


    <!-- -->
    <http auto-config="true"  use-expressions="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/logout" access="permitAll"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/register" access="permitAll"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/admin/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />

        <form-login login-page="/login" 
            authentication-failure-url="/login?error" 
            default-target-url="/dashboard"
            username-parameter="email"
            password-parameter="password"/>

        <access-denied-handler error-page="/login?error"/>

        <logout invalidate-session="true" 
            logout-success-url="/login" 
            logout-url="/j_spring_security_logout"
            delete-cookies="JSESSIONID"/>

        <session-management invalid-session-url="/login">
            <concurrency-control max-sessions="1" expired-url="/login"/>
        </session-management>

        <!-- 
        <remember-me token-validity-seconds="1209600"
                    remember-me-parameter="remember-me"/>
         -->            
    </http>

    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="loginManager" >
            <password-encoder hash="bcrypt" />
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>


</beans:beans>
```

And this is my spring-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache http://www.springframework.org.schema/cache/spring-cache.xsd">



    <context:component-scan base-package="com.isad" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <mvc:default-servlet-handler/>
    <!-- 
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/WEB-INF/" cache-period="31556926"/>
     -->
    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
    <!-- 
        Initialize base viewers 
    --> 
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/jsp/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>


    <!-- 
        Enable Data Transaction to Database. 
    -->
    <bean id="sessionFactory" scope="singleton"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml"></property>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
    <bean id ="transactionManager" class = "org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name = "sessionFactory" ref = "sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>   
</beans>
```

The login and register page would display normally if I don't want to apply spring-security. Any hints please.

This is my login and register controller:

```
@Controller
public class RegisterController {

    @Autowired private RegisterService regManager;

    @RequestMapping(value="/register", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showRegisterPage() {
        return "register";
    }


    @RequestMapping(value="/register", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String registerForm(@RequestParam(value="email") final String email,
                        @RequestParam(value="password") final String password) {
        regManager.registerAccount(email, password);
        return "redirect:/dashboard";
    }
}


@Controller
public class LoginController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/login", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showLoginForm() {
        return "login";
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post controller class responsible for login and register?

Comment: maybe this is a silly question, but did you write the /login page in your app ? you can also write login.html and then write the HTML page (without controller)

Comment: I just updated the code with login and register controller. I also have 3 pages login.jsp register.jsp and dashboard.jsp located under WEB-INF/views/

Comment: I found the cause. I forgot to change ViewResolver to /WEB-INF/views. Thank for your time.